# How to link the path of a folder situated in public.html for a random video player?

Tags: php, directory, paths

I'm new to coding and I'm struggling a bit with migrating my code to wordpress. I made a Random Video player with PHP to play a random file from specific folder on load. I tested it locally and everything works!

```
<?php
    $files = glob("randomizer/*.*");
    $randomFile = $files[array_rand($files)];
    $supported_file = array(
        'webm',
        'mp4',
        'gif',
    );
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($randomFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if ($ext == 'webm') {
            echo '<video width="960" height="540" controls> <source src="' . $randomFile . '" type="video/webm"/>';
            echo '</video>';
        } else if ($ext == 'mp4') {
            echo '<video  width="960" height="540" controls> <source src="' . $randomFile . '" type="video/mp4"/>';
            echo '</video>';
        } else {
            echo '<img src="' . $randomFile . '" alt="random image" />';
        }
?>
```

Now I need to bring it to Wordpress. I already have a folder in my 'public.html' named 'randomizer' containing all the webm & mp4 to pick from. What would be the way to link specific directory path in my code?

Thanks you!

Comment: where is your code located? Normally you'd implement this in a plugin or theme, which means you can use standard WordPress APIs such as `get_plugin_path` or `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` but by hardcoding it to a subfolder of `public.html` you've thrown all that out the window and would have to hardcode all the paths or at least the path to the randomized videos folder

Comment: Currently it's not located anywhere since I got stuck at the 'wordpress directory path' part. The code works locally, but I thought it was pointless to try to add it now if there is no directory to use files from anyway, so I had to figure that out first.  I was planning to use a plugin like codesnippet or see if there's a way to add php to an elementor page. You say something about harcoding the path to the video folder, how would that work?

Comment: using a plugin like code snippet will make the task much harder as now the PHP code has no location on the filesystem to reference. As for hardcoding, i mean literally writing it out by hand without using API functions, e.g. `$variable = "I am a hardcoded static string";`. I strongly advise you set up a plugin, and a real actual plugin with a folder and file on the filesystem not one created via another plugin such as code snippets. Creating plugins is trivial, it's a PHP file with a comment at the top that contains "Plugin Name: Your Plugin Name" in the plugins folder.

Comment: I'd also suggest using JS not PHP for the randomisation, by doing it server side any attempt to cache the page will cache the randomised video and cached users will always see the same video. I think most of the difficulty of your question is because you don't know where your code should go, and if you don't know the answer to that then you can't know the answer to this. Once the code is moved into a theme or plugin it become 1000x easier. I'd also look into shortcodes and blocks

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am slightly familiar with the formula to create a shortcode through some past experimentation so I will keep that in mind. I will go dig into building plugins and see how to import them into wordpress :) Thanks for the tip for JS. I saw a lot of similarities between php and JS in how it's written, so I'll look into how I could rewrite my php code for JS instead. I might come back later with questions but I have a better direction of where to look now!

Comment: SO CLOSE! the shape of what is a video player shows up, but can't load a video. If I right click I see the name of what should be the file though. Console is saying "HTTP load failed with status 404.". I'm now trying to rewrite with JS instead see if I have any better luck.

Comment: Other update, figured out something that works well - which is straight up importing my html file, php and randomizer folder in a new public.html folder to create a custom html page.

Comment: without knowing what you did to integrate it into WP it's not possible to help, you'd have to edit your question to say what you did, importantly _where_ you put the shortcode you tried to add, and what the 404s where.